# Finding a point on a bezier surface using De Casteljau's algorithm

Tags: numerical-methods, bezier-curve

Given $16$ control points $(x,y,z)$ of a bicubic bezier patch, how do I use De Casteljau's algorithm to generate a point $(s,t) = (0.5, 0.2)$ on the surface?

As far as I understand, this kind of bezier patch can be thought of $4$ curves along the $s$ parameter. To find the $z$ I mentioned above I have to solve each of the $4$ $s$-curves for the value $s=0.5$. How do I do this? Using $4$ points means I have a $n=3$ bezier curve with a starting point and an ending point as well as two respective points for the tangents. Solving this I should have $4$ new points to make up a new curve which I can evaluate at $t=0.2$.

Where do I start and what do I need to do? How is the Bernstein Polynomial related to this?

You can find the points here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYE2u.png

Please excuse me my not-so-good english skills or wrong usage of mathematical terminologyas it's not my first language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a good explanation starting [on this web page](http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/).

I recommend that you read the three sections on Bezier surfaces in "Unit 8".

The process you described in your question is roughly correct.

Let's call the 16 points:
$$P_{11}, P_{12}, P_{13}, P_{14}$$ 
$$P_{21}, P_{22}, P_{23}, P_{24}$$ 
$$P_{31}, P_{32}, P_{33}, P_{34}$$ 
$$P_{41}, P_{42}, P_{43}, P_{44}$$

And let $\phi_1$, $\phi_2$, $\phi_3$, $\phi_4$ be the Bernstein polynomials of degree 3.

Suppose we want to evaluate a point on the surface with parameter values $(s,t) = (0.5, 0.2)$.

The first thing we do is use the 16 points four at-a-time to construct four curves. We start with the points of the first row: $P_{11}$, $P_{12}$, $P_{13}$, $P_{14}$. We can use them to construct a Bezier curve
$$
C_1(s) = \phi_1(s)P_{11} + \phi_2(s)P_{12} + \phi_3(s)P_{13} + \phi_4(s)P_{14} = 
\sum_{j=1}^4 \phi_j(s)P_{1,j}
$$
Then, on this curve, we can calculate the point $Q_1 = C_1(0.5)$ at value $s=0.5$.
$$
Q_1 = C_1(0.5) = \sum_{j=1}^4 \phi_j(0.5)P_{1,j}
$$ 
You can calculate $Q_1$ by the normal de Casteljau algrorithm, or any other method.

We do the same things with the other three rows of points. For each row, we construct a Bezier curve, and then we calculate the point at parameter value $s=0.5$. We get points 
$$\text{second row:}\quad  Q_2 = C_2(0.5) = \sum_{j=1}^4 \phi_j(0.5)P_{2,j}$$
$$\text{third row:}\quad   Q_3 = C_3(0.5) = \sum_{j=1}^4 \phi_j(0.5)P_{3,j}$$
$$\text{fourth row:}\quad  Q_4 = C_4(0.5) = \sum_{j=1}^4 \phi_j(0.5)P_{4,j}$$
We can write all this more tidily as:
$$
Q_i = C_i(0.5) = \sum_{j=1}^4 \phi_j(0.5)P_{ij}  \quad (i=1,2,3,4)
$$

Now we just do the Bezier thing in the other direction -- we use the points $Q_1$, $Q_2$, $Q_3$, $Q_4$ to construct a Bezier curve Q(t) given by
$$
Q(t) = \phi_1(t)Q_1 + \phi_2(t)Q_2 + \phi_3(t)Q_3 + \phi_4(t)Q_4 =
\sum_{i=1}^4 \phi_i(t)Q_i
$$
Then our final surface point is the point at parameter value $t=0.2$ on the curve $Q(t)$:
$$
X(0.5, 0.2) = Q(0.2) = \sum_{i=1}^4 \phi_i(0.2)Q_i
$$
Again, you can calculate this point using the de Casteljau algorithm or any other method.

To understand how all this relates to the surface equation, let's substitute the expressions for the $Q_i$ into our last equation. We get
$$
X(0.5, 0.2)  = \sum_{i=1}^4 \phi_i(0.2)Q_i  = 
\sum_{i=1}^4 \phi_i(0.2)\left(\sum_{j=1}^4 \phi_j(0.5)P_{ij}\right) 
$$
Rearranging this gives:
$$
X(0.5, 0.2)  = \sum_{i=1}^4 \sum_{j=1}^4 \phi_j(0.5) \phi_i(0.2) P_{ij}
$$
You should recognize the right-hand side as the formula for a Bezier surface.

Here's a picture:

[image: bezier-patch]

The blue curves are $C_1$, $C_2$, $C_3$, $C_4$, the red dots are $Q_1$, $Q_2$, $Q_3$, $Q_4$, and the red curve is $Q$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this extreme good explanation!! you saved my day! =)